# MongoDB schema design - finding the last X comments across all blog posts filtered by user

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I am trying to reproduce the classic blog schema of one `Post` to many `Comment`s using Morphia and the Play Framework.

My schema in Mongo is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d941c960c68c4e20d6a9abf"), 
 "className" : "models.Post", 
  "title" : "An amazing blog post", 
  "comments" : [
    {
        "commentDate" : NumberLong("1301552278491"),
        "commenter" : {
            "$ref" : "SiteUser",
            "$id" : ObjectId("4d941c960c68c4e20c6a9abf")
        },
        "comment" : "What a blog post!"
    },
    {
        "commentDate" : NumberLong("1301552278492"),
        "commenter" : {
            "$ref" : "SiteUser",
            "$id" : ObjectId("4d941c960c68c4e20c6a9abf")
        },
        "comment" : "This is another comment"
    }
]}
```

I am trying to introduce a social networking aspect to the blog, so I would like to be able to provide on a `SiteUser`'s homepage the last X comments by that `SiteUser`'s friends, across all posts.

My models are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Post extends Model {

    public String title;

    @Embedded
    public List<Comment> comments;

}

@Embedded
public class Comment extends Model {

    public long commentDate;

    public String comment;

    @Reference
    public SiteUser commenter;

}
```

From what I have read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224811/mongodb-schema-design-for-blogs/5226609#5226609), I think I need to run the following against the database (where `[a, b, c]` represents the `SiteUser`s) :

```
db.posts.find( { "comments.commenter" : {$in: [a, b, c]}} )
```

I have a `List<SiteUser>` to pass in to Morphia for the filtering, but I don't know how to

1. set up an index on `Post` for `Comments.commenter` from within Morphia
2. actually build the above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either put `@Indexes(@Index("comments.commenter"))` on the `Post` class, or `@Indexed` on the `commenter` field of the `Comment` class (Morphia's `Datastore.ensureIndexes()` will recurse in the classes and correctly create the `comments.commenter` index on the `Post` collection)
2. I think `ds.find(Post.class, "comments.commenter in", users)` would work, `ds` being a `Datastore` and `users` your `List<SiteUser>` (I don't use `@Reference` though, so I can't confirm; you might have to first extract the list of their `Key`s).

Comment: re your second point, won't that return instances of Post? I'm looking for instances of Comment across all Posts. (Sorry for the late reply, I've been away from a computer)

Comment: Yes, it will return `Post` instances. I don't think you can get `Comment` instances directly, given that they are `@Embedded` objects. There's no way with MongoDB to do that; eventually _virtual collections_ will make it possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138454/filtering-embedded-documents-in-mongodb/2140125#2140125

Comment: re the second point: Since you are using PlayMorphia module, an easy way to query is `Post post = Post.q().filter("comments.commeter in", users).get()`