# Is it possible to query for a specific object in an array with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Say you have a blog collection like this

`{"title": "Post Title", "body": "Post Body", "comments": [{"user": "user1", "comment": "comment from user1"}, {"user": "user2", "comment": "comment from user2"}]}
{"title": "Post Title 2", "body": "Post Body 2", "comments": [{"user": "user1", "comment": "comment from user1"}]}`

How can I query for the comments from a user?

This query works but returns comments from user2 as well as user1.
`db.posts.find({"comments.user": "user1"})`

Is there any way to get only the comments from user1?

Comment: I asked the same question a few months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way since Mongo just returns the whole document when it finds a match, you may be able to do it with Map/Reduce or server processing

Answer (score 1):

This feature request can probably help you... when it will be implemented (some months if no delay).

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828

Comment: So I guess they missed the less than a week about 7 weeks ago. Hopefully this will be released someday, but until then I guess I am stuck with the Map/Reduce that jeff suggested.