# MongoDB design - tags

Tags: mongodb, tags

I'm new with MongoDB. I have a design question, about performance of MongoDB. Lets say I have  the class Movies with two properties, Name and Director. Also I want to tag this Movie Class. Is better to add a new propertie of strings[] to this class, or to create a new class MovieTags? **I know I will query this tags a lot because I will use an autocomplete on the UI. For this autocomplete function I only need the tags, not  the Movie object**. 
What option is better? add a propertie of strings[] or reference to a collection of MovieTags?  Thinking in performance... of course in both cases the indexing will be done.

Should I use a MapReduce? To only select the tags, for the autocomplete function if I use an embebed string[] object? How?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb schema design for blogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224811/mongodb-schema-design-for-blogs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement post tags in Mongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455685/how-to-implement-post-tags-in-mongo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably go with a schema like this, which stores the tags in a string array field:

```
db.movies.insert({
    name: "The Godfather",
    director: "Francis Ford Coppola",
    tags: [ "mafia", "wedding", "violence" ]
})

db.movies.insert({
    name: "Pulp Fiction",
    director: "Quentin Tarantino",
    tags: [ "briefcase", "violence", "gangster" ]
})

db.movies.insert({
    name: "Inception",
    director: "Christopher Nolan",
    tags: [ "dream", "thief", "subconscious" ]
})
```

You wouldn't need map-reduce for this type of query.  By embedding the tags inside the the movie document you can take advantage of MongoDB's [multikey](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) feature, and find movies with a given tag using single [find()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying) query like this:

```
db.movies.find( { tags: "dream" } )
```

And like you said, it's also worth adding an index to the multikey array to improve query performance:

```
db.movies.ensureIndex( { tags: 1 } )
```

Comment: The problem, with this is that you select the hole movie object, when I only need the tags for the autocomplete. Are you sure this is faster?

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually answer his question. How would you go about getting a distinct list of tags used in the entire movie collection?

Comment: This will get you a distinct list of tags: `db.test.distinct('tags')`

Answer (score 2):

You can always filter the fields that are returned as part of the query result.

The link to the docs that details how to do so is http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#Querying-FieldSelection

This will let you filter out parts of the movie object that you re not interested in.