# MongoDB AND SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I'm working on a project where some objects are best suited for a document database.  We chose mongoDO, which I really like.

The question is, how are people representing child objects that are in a document but are actually in SQL?

For example, if my "user" object is in SQL, and my order object is in mongo

Class order {
   User user;
   DateTime dateCreated;
   double Price;
}

Should I just store the userId?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb schema design for blogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224811/mongodb-schema-design-for-blogs)

Comment: google for "mongodb schema design" - this has been really asked a bunch of times on SO and on various MongoDB related forums.

Comment: I dont see how thats a duplicate at all - it has nothing in there about having an object stored in mongo that has children in SQL Server.

Comment: I've tried googling of course, i didnt see any good examples.  Perhaps you could show me a link?

Comment: Be serious - every documentation speaks about how to deal with a replacements of JOINs and how to manage relations: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Comment: I fully understand how "joins" work in Mongo - I'm not sure you're reading my question correctly.  How would that object look if Users is in SQL server, and order is in Mongo?  Would it be just the UserId in mongo?

Comment: You are the one who probably doesn't read his answer correctly.. Does it really matter whether the user is in SQL or in Mongo?

Comment: Ok - so if it doesnt matter, then what would the User object be?  How would I denote that the data pulls from sql?  I see that the c# driver has DBRef, but that is for pulling a reference out of mongo instead of and external SQL Server

Comment: So you guys think these documents have information about how to create a relationship with SQL Server and Mongo?  I must just not be finding it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store its ID.

You might also want to store some of the attributes of the user so you don't have to look up what's in the SQL DB... for example a shipping address is a good choice to store here since even if the user a couple of days later changes his shipping address you still want to have the old address here.

Don't store the attributes which you have to refresh when they change.

Comment: Thats kind of what I was thinking - it just stinks to have my object influenced so much by how I'm storing it.  I'm going to do a little more investigation

Comment: With freedom comes responsibility.