# How to design a MongoDB for blog?

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I'm building a simple blog system for multiple `users`, they can access data by `userID`, `username` and `nodeID`(blog).

In RDBMS, normally we will have `user`/`table`/`ownership` tables. In mongoDB, some suggest to put them in a single `users` collection. However, as far as i know, it could be very slow if `users` want to access specific `nodeID`, since mongoDB may go through every document. Indexing will significantly drop the create speed, in my case, that means both `createUser()` and `createNode()`, right?

Therefore, is there any "Best Practices" we can follow?
Thanks.

Comment: *"Indexing will significantly drop the create speed"* – how often are you inserting new data that this is a concern? "Significantly" still just means a few milliseconds most likely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb schema design for blogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224811/mongodb-schema-design-for-blogs)

Comment: There are a few posts that you can refer for that. Here I'm listing a few : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224811/mongodb-schema-design-for-blogs

https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-melbourne-2012/schema-design-example

https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: @deceze: few milliseconds at worst :)

Comment: checkout this course that has a POC creating a mongodb for blog https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about

Comment: Great! I'm going to read them 1 by 1. In fact I didn't find much official performance benchmark, therefore tutorials are the main sources. Some says _"If you use `ensureIndex()` for a field, you have half performance due to its mechanism, so just use `_id` to `find`"_. Well I have to say that's really confusing. Perhaps people exaggerate that performance issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Three Collections** Inside the DB, Namely,

```
"Users", 
"UserPosts", 
"UserComments"
```

**Users** Collection's Field could be

```
"name",
"age",
"occupation",
"profileImage",
"numberOfPosts", 
"birthdate", 
"joiningDate", 
"session"
```

etc.

**UserPosts** Collection's Field could be

```
    "Id", 
    "revisionId",
    "author",
    "type",
    "language",
    "userId",
    "status",
    "title",
    "tags",
    "content"
```

etc.

**UserComments** Collection's Field could be

```
    "Id", 
    "userPostId",
    "author",
    "type",
    "language",
    "userId",
    "status",
    "comment",
```

etc.

*User Comment will be maintained by UserPostId Field It contains.*

Comment: Thanks! That looks exactly what we did in RDBMS, isn't it? Do you think it's necessary to use `db.UserPosts.ensureIndex({author:1})` and  `db.UserComments.ensureIndex({author:1, userPostId:1})` for better performance(or just worse)?

Comment: No You did not need to do that.